# Receive email if a bounty is in my subscribed tags

Tags: discussion, bounty, email, subscriptions

Is there an option to receive emails about bounties that have been offered on tags that I am watching?

(If not, is there any reason against such a feature?)

Comment: That's a lot of mail tho. ~50 bounty per day, That's a lot of mail. EG: Javascript has 1.2M followers and 6 bounties per day. Email delivery is never guaranted, will be easier to just query the Api.

Comment: And btw If the question is in the mail even just the title this will be a open door for spam. If the question and its title is not in the mail. Well the mail will be less usefull as you will have to click and read the question. How mutch will spammer sell those advertising space where they have stat of numbers of view and good chance almost of viewers read the spam? For 1M mail it's about 75$, for those premium targeted spam I expect it to be more than 100.

Comment: Maybe I miss something but having an extra subscription for a few newly created bounties, which is sent only to those who actively subscribe to such a message (not 1.2M Js followers need to be JS bounty subscribers) seems not that much load compared to the daily questions.

Comment: Regarding the spam - do you receive subscriptions currently?